# What is the driver for Oracle 10g database for java 6,7, or 8

Tags: java, oracle10g, java-7, java-6

What is apropriate driver to connect to Oracle 10g databse?

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
```

And I am getting

> java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: oracle/jdbc/OracleDriver : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-10201-088211.html

Comment: Please provide the output from "java -version".

Comment: Please provide the name of the JDBC Jar you're using.

Comment: 1.8.0_45. I can connect it in netbeaeans services with ojdbc7.jar
https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/oracle-db.html#start This is working, but cannt get  Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(...);

Comment: And where can't you connect? On the server? Then what is the Java version on the server?

Answer (score 3):

For Oracle database connection:

Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

Answer (score 1):

> java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: oracle/jdbc/OracleDriver :
>   Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

This tells you that you're using a JAR compiled for Java SE 7, but you're using a JRE < v7.

For Oracle 10g database there seems to be only unsupported JDBC drivers for older Java versions, but I guess you can use them with newer Java versions, too:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-10201-088211.html

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this page http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-faq-090281.html#01_03 for more details on the JDK version supported by JDBC drivers.  10.2 version support JDK4.
However, you can use higher version of the driver with older version of the database.